# How to stop unauthorized installation of programs on Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, installation, windows-installation

On my windows 8.1, everyday or other some programs are **automatically installed**. Eg. Deals100, CouponDunia etc. *I want to enforce a password to install anything on my machine*. Dont tell to create a user with minimum permissions as I always want administrator to be logged in.

Comment: Only way to enforce a windows password is to run a limited account.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to Your problem is UAC

```
Open the Control Panel (icons view), and click/tap on the User Accounts icon.

Click/tap on the Change User Account Control settings link.
OR    
Go to the Search Charm and type “Change User Account Settings”

Move the slider up.
```

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-user-account-control-on-off#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Did You manage to solve the problem? If You solved it with this method, please accept the solution. If You have other questions, feel confident to ask. If You solved it with another method, please answer your own question with your method (at least in a few words), so we can close the post.